# ActiveMQ Monitoring / logging for all Messages om all Queues

Tags: activemq-classic

Is there a simple way to log (perhaps partially log) all messages that pass through all queues on ActiveMQ? The logging-interceptor does NOT do it.

Yes, I understand its somewhat ludicrous, but its still a requirement.

How about from a Camel context?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Achieved by embedding a camel context with a message handler. Then we wiretap any queue that we want to log and let the handler consume from the queue. The handler sends messages to any database you like.

Logged.

Answer (score 2):

I was looking around for an answer like this, and there's actually a relatively simple way to do this now - Mirrored Queues.
http://activemq.apache.org/mirrored-queues.html